# Is there a gem for consuming JSON-API formatted RESTful json api's | Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rest, json-api

Is there a library for consuming and parsing [JSON:API format](http://jsonapi.org) in a Rails application. I feel like the model objects should look like ActiveRecord objects once a request is returned, similar to [ActiveResource](https://github.com/rails/activeresource) or [Flexirest](https://github.com/flexirest/flexirest). However, the issue is both of the those leave me not much better of the using a more generic http adapter like [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday). I'm having to do some fancy handling to extract deeply nested arrays and hashes, Not to mention representing associations.

I'm wondering how others are handling this context. I think part of the problem I'm having is that "Json api" is a little tricky to google with the clutter of related content.

Comment: I can't answer any more, but have you seen https://github.com/flexirest/flexirest/blob/master/docs/json-api.md

Answer (score 2):

for my project i use rest-client `https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client` easy to use some example require

```
'rest-client'

RestClient.get 'http://example.com/resource'

RestClient.get 'http://example.com/resource', {:params => {:id => 50, 'foo' => 'bar'}}

RestClient.get 'https://user:password@example.com/private/resource', {:accept => :json}

RestClient.post 'http://example.com/resource', :param1 => 'one', :nested => { :param2 => 'two' }

RestClient.delete 'http://example.com/resource'
```

and can parse `JSON` like this

```
resource = RestClient::Resource.new 'http://example.com/resource'
json = JSON.parse(resource)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: The real issue is what you get back from an api formatted with jsonapi-resource. Checkout [jsonapi.org](http://jsonapi.org/). Of course I can just key in to the components. It just get to be a lot of repetition and that approach negates all the context that is returned, like relationships.

Comment: Are you try JSONAPI::Resources

Answer (score 2):

[json_api_client](https://github.com/chingor13/json_api_client) is the most robust, full-featured client I know about, when it comes to automatic parsing and utilization of all of the parts of JSON:API.  It's definitely not totally mature yet (not thread-safe, all results are returned as sets -
 including single `find`s, customization options are limited to injecting full replacements for certain modules/methods)

But it's pretty great for very standard use-cases - particularly if you have the authority to write the API's URL structure to match what is expected by this library.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) to consume an API, and [json-api-vanilla](https://github.com/trainline/json-api-vanilla) to parse the response. Very easy to use:

```
response = RestClient.get(url, headers = authorization_header)
doc = JSON::Api::Vanilla.parse(response.body)

doc.data[0].comments[1].author.last_name
```